# What is the name of the shape of the iron core in a transformer?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, electrical-engineering

I'm researching on transformers and curious to know about what this shape is called (the actual core block, ignore the wires around it).

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the literal name of the 3D solid?

Answer (score 8):

This mathematical shape is a particularly simple example of a [toroidal polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_polyhedron).

Comment: Yes, the mathematical shape is what I am looking for. It seemed similar to the torus to me except that it's square and not circular. Toroidal polyhedron I guess would be the closest then. I'm curious why the shape in itself has no name.

Answer (score 7):

That can be called a [*core-type transformer*](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=421-01-07) (with a single window) in contrast to the [*shell-type transformer*](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=421-01-09). Note also that those types of cores are also constructed with [*laminated*](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=151-14-03) materials to reduce eddy current losses.

The linked definitions from the *Electrotechnical Vocabulary* of the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) give the above terms as deprecated, but they are well established nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking for the name of the squared ring of iron that connects the two coils in a core-type transformer, it is called the “yoke.”  The iron yokes together the two coils, like a wagon yoke held together the two oxen pulling a wagon.

Comment: I'm actually curious of the name of the shape. "Squared ring" seems to be closest to what I'm looking for.